Добавление маркеров на карте мира на subplots в folium
Приведите пример кода, пожалуйста. Нигде еще не видела подобного, да и у самой не получается. Высвечивается маленький сабплот с картой мира, но без нужных меток
fig = branca.element.Figure()
df1=iata_arports[iata_arports['Continents']=='Africa']
m1 = fig.add_subplot(3, 4, 1)
m1.add_child(folium.Map())
for i in range(0,len(df1)):
    folium.Marker(location=[df1.iloc[i]['Latitude'], df1.iloc[i]['Longitude']]).add_to(m1)
fig

В этом коде я фильтрую данные по континентам и хочу визуализировать на отдельных семи (столько континентов) сабплотах каждый континент с помеченными метками(маркерами) с местонахождением аэропортов. На первой фотке это то что у меня получилось. Вторая фотка - то, что я хочу получить но на маленьких сабплотах. Код на второй фотке аналогичен коду с первой за исключением наличия сабплотов.



Вы немного неверно понимаете работу folium api.
Вам сначала нужно создать объект-карту; эту карту вы добавляете как потомка для сабплота branca, и в этот объект а не в сапблот,  добавить маркеры:
import folium
import branca 
fig = branca.element.Figure()
m = fig.add_subplot(3, 4, 1)
africa = folium.Map([1, 25], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=2)
folium.Marker(location=[-1.286389,  36.817222], popup="Nairobi").add_to(africa)
m.add_child(africa)
fig



Cпасибо вам большое.Все получилось!!!
